# primary key with auto_increment, after deleting the original rows, PK starts does not start from beginning

Tags: mysql

```
productID INT UNSIGNED   NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT 


1001
1002
.....
1006
```

After deleting the original rows it starts with `1007` when you add new rows.
Any suggestions to change it back to start with 1001 with already large amount of data?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? An auto generated artificial key has no meaning whatsoever. So it does not matter whether a new row gets the value 1007, 2587, or 424242

Comment: it looks more consistent

Comment: Again: the values of an artificial (generated) PK column are **completely** meaningless, so they can not "look more consistent".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An auto-increment number is **not** intended to fill the gaps.

Think about it. It only needs to generate a **unique** number. The fastest way is to add `1` to the latest given number. Otherwise the **all** other records would need to be changed when you delete something. That is unnecessary and slow.

#### And never mess with an auto-generated field. Leave it as is!

Comment: do you have any solution to make it start with 1001, I mean the new records